# Scroll speed slows down after a long period

Tags: mouse, 19.04, mouse-scroll

This has seemed to happen after I updated from Ubuntu `18.10` to `19.04`, so I am not sure if it is because of the update or not.

But the issue that I am having, is that if I leave my computer running for a few days the scroll speed when scrolling the mouse wheel in all my applications (Chrome, Spotify, vscode, Nautilus, etc.) drastically decreases until I restart my computer then the scroll speed works as it did before.

Comment: Looks like the answer is to power off the mouse and turn it back on instead of the computer.

Answer (score 8):

> Looks like the answer is to power off the mouse and turn it back on instead of the computer.

You are my hero for the day and I can't believe that actually worked. I guess the old "have you tried turning it off and back on" still applies.

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please do a comment when you're directly referring to an answer.

Comment: Be happy to! Could have swore it said I didn't have enough rep to comment yesterday, which I thought was a little odd, but maybe it was reply because I didn't even notice "comment" on the desktop. Sorry!

Comment: Actually, it does say I cant comment without 50 rep. I'll just hold off on commenting until I have the rep I suppose.

Comment: I can't believe this worked...